# Populate VueSimpleSuggest from URL param on page load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, getparameter, vue-simple-suggest

I have this VueSimpleSuggest component in my Vue JS app:

```
<vue-simple-suggest
  class="input-elements"
  v-model="chosen"
  :max-suggestions="0"
  :list="getList"
  :filter-by-query="true"
  ref="suggestComponent"
  v-on:select="updateAppDataOnSelect"
>
</vue-simple-suggest>
```

I have this in the `script` section of the `vue` file:

data() {
return {
chosen: ''
}
},

I am trying to pick up the URL parameter `fd` with the query parameter and assign it so it is effectively the default value for the simple suggest list:

```
mounted() {
  if ("fd" in this.$route.query) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('fd: ', this.$route.query.fd)
    this.chosen = self.$route.query.fd
  }
},
```

While the `console.log` dumps out the value of the `fd` parameter, the simple suggest input does not show that value.

How do I get the simple suggest to show the value passed in from the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong parent reference. I should have had `this` instead of `self`, as demonstrated by the `console.log` #typo

```
mounted() {
  if ("fd" in this.$route.query) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('fd: ', this.$route.query.fd)
    this.chosen = this.$route.query.fd
  }
},
```